# Definition of modular form

Tags: modular-forms

There is a well known definition of modular form

Let $f:\mathbb{H}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$, $\Gamma=\Gamma_0(N)$ and $k\in\mathbb{Z}$

(i)$f$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{H}$

(ii)$f|_k\gamma=f$ for any $\gamma\in\Gamma$

(iii)$f$ is meromorphic(resp holomorphic, vanishing) at all cusps of $\Gamma$

For (iii), this can be stated as following way

For any $\gamma\in SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$, $f|_k\gamma(z)=\sum\limits_{n=n_0}^{\infty}a_nq_h^n$ for some $n_0\in\mathbb{Z}$(resp $n_0=0,n_0\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0})$

My question is that whether (iii) is equivalent to (iii)' or not

(iii)' $f|_k\gamma(z)=O(e^{\epsilon y})$ for some $\epsilon>0$ as $y\rightarrow\infty$(resp $f|_k\gamma(z)=O(1)$, $f|_k\gamma(z)=O(e^{\epsilon y})$ for some $\epsilon<0$ as $y\rightarrow\infty)$

Thank you!

Comment: If $\Gamma=\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ , then $q=e^{2\pi iz}$. We are using that $\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$ is in your $\Gamma$ and so your modular form satisifes $f(z+1)=f(z)$. In particular, you are taking a Fourier expansion. As $z\to i\infty$, $q\to 0$ so the growth of your modular form as you go up to imaginary axis is equivalent to asking the behavior of your Fourier series when $q\to 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is equivalent.

As $f(z) = f(\gamma z)$ for any $\gamma \in \Gamma_0(N)$, we see that $f$ is periodic and has a Fourier expansion (at any cusp, though I stick only to $\infty$ in this answer) $f(z) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} a(n) q^n$. Coordinates in $q$ both describe the Fourier expansion and the Riemannian chart near the cusp. Your statements are all immediate from the behavior in $q$ of the $q$-expansion.

For example, meromorphy (at this particular cusp) is equivalent to there existing an $N$ such that $a(n) = 0$ for all $n < N$, which is equivalent to to $\lvert f(q) \rvert \ll q^{N}$ as $q \to 0$ in the Fourier expansion.